# Amazon AWS RAID Configuration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a newbie in using Amazon AWS Elastic Compute cloud (EC2).
Currently, I am using an instance and have attached 1TB EBS Volume to the same.
Now I want my disk space to be 2TB since I am falling short of space.
One solution is to configure a RAID of 2 GB.

If I create a RAID with 2 EBS volume (one is old and having data inside it and the other will be new) will the data persist on the old one ?

Thanks,
Siddharth

Answer (score 1):

nope. when you setup the raid array that operation is destructive. 
What you could do in your case is resize the volume.
stop -> snapshot -> resize -> reattach -> start

where "resize" = create a new volume from the snapshot that is larger than the original, then resize the partition on he new volume if there is one, then resize the filesystem to fit the partition or volume. Or, perhaps better, build a new volume and use LVM, so you have more flexibility next time, then copy the files (thanks @Michael-sqlbot for extra clarification)

Comment: "resize" = create a new volume from the snapshot that is larger than the original, then resize the partition on he new volume if there is one, then resize the filesystem to fit the partition or volume.  Or, perhaps better, build a new volume and use LVM, so you have more flexibility next time, then copy the files.